# Selenium,PhpUnit: Alert or PopUp message with selenium webdriver and phpunit

Tags: selenium, popup, webdriver, phpunit, alert

I want to display an alert , popup that i can have an idea about the test process even correct or not but i can't

This is my code

```
    public function setUp(){

    $capabilities = array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME =>'firefox');
    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',$capabilities);
    }

     public function formSubmit(){
     $formE = $this->webDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xPath('//*[@id="feedback"]/ul/li'));
     IF ( $formE->isDisplayed()){
         // the alert or the popup 
     }
     }
```

So could you please help me to figure out a solution.
Thank you. B.Marwen

Comment: Is the popup an alert or a HTML dialog?

Comment: I think an alert is better for my case

Comment: Why would you want to throw an alert or popup? Typically you would just log a pass/fail and move on.

Comment: what i need is how to check if the test end with success / fail , that the tester can know this result !! and i don't know how to do this. Merci

Comment: You log pass/fail in a file. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: what yo mean by pass/fail , could you give me an example please ?